# Is there a better way to implement static method that I use in multiple classes?

Tags: java

I have this static method which returns a string from a yml file by given parameters. I use this in over 20 classes and currently I just paste this code into each class. Is there better way to access that method from each class without needing to copy paste it all over? Thanks in advance.

```java
private static String msgYml(String message) {
        return ConfigMgr.getMessages().getString(message);
    }
```

Comment: Make it public?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a static method in `util` class that accepts `ConfigMgr` and `String`, so you can pass the appropriate `ConfigMgr`

```
public class YamlUtil {

   public static String getYmlProps(ConfigMgr configMgr, String prop) {
       return configMgr.getMessages().getString(prop);
      }
 }
```